# How to convert different time formats to "%Y-%m-%d" using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, strftime

I am trying to convert any date format "%Y-%m-%d". On my code, I am getting a TypeError datetime.date doesn't apply to an 'str' object.

```
def open_csv2():
    browse_text2.set("Proccessing CSV...")
    csv2file = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, title="Select the CSV", filetypes=[("Text file", "*.csv")])
    
    if csv2file:
        df = pd.read_csv(csv2file, usecols=['date'])
        
        dates = df['date']
        
        new_dates = []
        for i in dates:
            n_date = datetime.strftime(i,"%Y-%m-%d")
            new_dates.append({'date':n_date})
            
        new_dates.to_csv('__newDates.csv', index=False)
                
                
        root.quit()
```

I am getting this error:
TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' for 'datetime.date' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object.

Thank you!

Comment: Use `strptime` to convert a string date which is presumably what `i` is, into a `datetime` object, then use `strftime` To format that as a string in your desired format. Read the documentation https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects it has many many examples you can use.

Comment: To diagnose, you could simply print `i` - although the error message is pretty clear, isn’t it.

Comment: Okay, so the error message is telling you that you have a `str`, in a place where you presumably expected to have a `datetime` object (in order to do the conversion). Do you see anything else in the `datetime` module documentation describing how to convert from `str` to `datetime`? (Hint: you will need to know the existing format.)

Comment: It appears that you believe that `i` is a `datetime`. But the error message says it is a `string`, and that agrees with your intent to *convert any date format*. To interpret unpredictably formatted dates, look at `dateutil.parser`.

Comment: Try `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` to convert the strings into `datetime`s

Answer (score 0):

Your `i` in `datetime.strftime(i,"%Y-%m-%d")` should be in a `datetime` format, not in a `str` format.

Your `df['date']` column is therefore probably in a `str` format, when you imported the dataframe from csv. Please check the `type` of data in the `date` column.

If you want to convert your `df['date']` to string, then you should use `datetime.strptime(i, "%Y-%m-%d")`, instead of the `strftime` function.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Because I am trying to convert different time formats. 
On my CSV file, I can see time formats in "yy/mm/dd", "mm/dd/yy", "mm-dd-yyyy".

And a whole lot of date time formats. I tried converting it first to strptime before strftime. But, I don't know what to pass as a second parameter to define all time formats.

Comment: Try using the ```strptime``` function instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below example:

```
Sample Data


Print(df)
         date
0  28-01-2020
1  15-02-2020
2  15-03-2020
3  25-03-2020
4  01-04-2020
5  30-05-2020
```

**See data-type:**

As you this is an obj datatype and not in `datetime` format.

```
print(df.dtypes)
date    object
dtype: object
```

**Datetime conversion:**

Just convert it to `datetime` and you will find the datatype chnaged.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
print(df)
        date
0 2020-01-28
1 2020-02-15
2 2020-03-15
3 2020-03-25
4 2020-01-04
5 2020-05-30

print(df.dtypes)
date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

### Also look at the help section, ie `help(pd.to_datetime)`:

```
Examples
--------
Assembling a datetime from multiple columns of a DataFrame. The keys can be
common abbreviations like ['year', 'month', 'day', 'minute', 'second',
'ms', 'us', 'ns']) or plurals of the same

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2015, 2016],
...                    'month': [2, 3],
...                    'day': [4, 5]})
>>> pd.to_datetime(df)
0   2015-02-04
1   2016-03-05
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```